# EOF in sequential fortran reads

Tags: io, fortran

When detecting EOF in fortran via the `IOSTAT` argument of `READ`, like this:

```
nLines=0
DO
  READ(unit,'(A)',IOSTAT=Error) Line
  IF (Error /= 0) EXIT
  nLines=nLines+1
END DO
```

When exactly does the `Error` variable get a non-zero value? Is it when the final line of the file is read or when a new read is attempted after that? Does it depend on whether the `END FILE` instruction was used when writing the file? Is it compiler-dependent?

If it is compiler-dependent, how could I count the number of lines in the file in more portable way?

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: @gnat I googled for "fortran stackexchange", found this one, it looked appropriate and more specific than Stack Overflow. But if it is more appropriate there, can the question be moved or should I re-post it there?

Comment: if you prefer it there, your options are either flag for moderator to migrate or delete here and post as a new question at SO

Comment: Jellby - you'll likely get a better answer from SO on this one as it's diving into the particulars of the language itself.  There are currently 3 votes to migrate to SO on your question.  With a little patience, your question will automatically migrate to SO and you won't need to re-post.

Answer (score 1):

The iostat argument gets a nonzero value when the read statement hasn't finished succesfully. Either an error happened, or an end of line or end of record condition has been encountered. The values of the variables being read are then undefined.

Therefore if the last record (line) in the file is formatted and terminated properly, the iostat argument will be zero after it has been read and it will be nonzero in subsequent read statements.

Answer (score 1):

The end-of-file condition, for which `Error` will get a non-zero value,  is triggered when the endfile record is read.  This endfile record is a separate record within the file (which needn't have a physical manifestation) and so, as [Vladimir F states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23844094/3157076), a correct "data" record will result in `Error` being zero.

The endfile record written by an `endfile` statement is always written as the "next record" so, in particular, the value of `Error` won't be non-zero when there has been a record read successfully, regardless of the use of `endfile`.

This "next record" also holds for a record being written through non-advancing I/O, so even in this case one doesn't see a (partially) read record and an end-of-file.

Finally, it's worth saying that on an end-of-file condition the value of `Error` will be set to the constant `IOSTAT_END` (from the intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env`) so you can check against this value to distinguish from a read error.

Comment: That's what I thought, and in that case my code in the question is "correct". But I've been observing the opposite behaviour (last record read, ``IOSTAT`` negative) with the Intel compilers in some systems, and it's "fixed" by adding the ``ENDFILE``. Annoyingly, I haven't been able to create a test case, so there seems to be something else going on.

Comment: Checking whether it's an end-of-file negative, or end-of-record negative (using the constants from `iso_fortran_env`) may be valuable.  `close`ing the file or normal program termination should place an endfile record in the file just as much as `endfile` does.  So perhaps also check that the writing program doesn't have error termination?  Possibly also that the file itself is terminated correctly for the system.

Comment: @Jellby read my last pararaph: " if the last record (line) in the file is formatted and terminated properly". This condition might be violated in your input file.

Comment: @VladimirF Yes, I'm aware of that, but the file is written by the same code with plain ``WRITE``s and ``CLOSE``, and it works fine with almost any compiler but Intel. I probably need to investigate further.